# Creating background job in java using crontab or ServletContextListener

Tags: java, multithreading, web-applications, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have to read data from database and write table data into file in json form then that data will be injected into an `API` daily around 5pm. for that I need to create `scheduler`. I have already created the code.

I have got 2 approach for it.

1. Creating simple java application with `main class`. Create a jar of it and run it in `unix box` by creating crontab job.
2. Create a `ServletContextListener` use the `ScheduledExecutorService` class and run the application.

so one is run by `unix` box and another one by web server.

Which approach is better. I have to introduce this facility in product so looking for best solution. Please help me to create best product. or if you can guide in which scenario which approach is better?

Comment: Shruti, please add specific case that only Java allowed. Is it possible to use any frameworks e.g. Spring or Play?

Comment: we have to use vanila java. Oracle uses OAF and ADF..even that is not allowed in this application

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use scripting language e.g. Groovy + crontab.

Pros:

- easy to write singe file code
- easy to get familiar with language
- dependency using Grape
- if OS will fail and recover crontab may restart itself

Cons:

- you need to remember OS you're working with
- maintenance of crontab (just don't know your awareness on Unix administration)

Comment: Thank you Alex. actually I work at Oracle and we are not allowed to use Groovy. we can use only java. Can you suggest some solution in java please?

Comment: For your specific case I would take first option: java main class + crontab. Hope that will help.